# Shell Script to Set CSV Column Width to Fit?

Tags: macos, shell, csv

Is it possible to format a csv from a shell script so that all the columns are set to fit?

Here is what I have, just not sure what else to change:

```
#! /bin/bash

saveDir="TJ"
dd=$(date -v -1d '+%Y-%m-%d')
for file in *.csv ; do
    saveName="${saveDir}/TJ - ${dd}.csv"
    cut -d',' -f2,14 "$file" > "$saveName"
done
```

Also, after cutting the columns and leaving only the 2nd and 14th column I have 3 extra blank columns.. how do I get rid of those?

Example file: http://d.pr/3a5Z

This is how I would like the CSV to be, displaying all text from both columns and cutting the extra columns out: http://d.pr/S1mz

EDIT:

```
#! /bin/bash

saveDir="TJ"
dd=$(date -v -1d '+%Y-%m-%d')
for file in *.csv ; do
    saveName="${saveDir}/TJ - ${dd}.csv"
    awk '{x="";for(i=2;i<=14;i++){if(length(x))x=x",";x=x$i;}print x;}' yourfile
done
```

Comment: Yes it is; Please post the current output and the expected ditto

Comment: @FredrikPihl http://d.pr/3a5Z is this what you mean?

Comment: I mean to update your question with one line of the output that you currently get and then how you would like to have it instead.

Comment: @FredrikPihl i dont understand sorry.. I just end up with the file as output

Comment: CSV files do not have a column width, they have rows of data and on each row the fields are separated by commas. HTML tables and Excel worksheets may have column widths, but CSV files do not.

Answer (score 2):

**GROSSLY EDITED**

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
saveDir="TJ"
dd=$(date -v -1d '+%Y-%m-%d')
for file in *.csv ; do
   saveName="${saveDir}/TJ - ${dd}.csv"
   awk '{x="";for(i=2;i<=14;i++){if(length(x))x=x",";x=x$i;}print x;}' $file > "$saveName"
done
```

Comment: I edited the main post with your suggestion.. I got a "Shell Script Failed" error so I'm not sure what went wrong since I replaced the cut command with what you suggested

Comment: I also tried your alternative suggestion by adding it under my cut command and still no luck

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `sed` to remove the three trailing commas

Input:

```
$ cat TJ\ -\ 2014-01-03.csv
name,number,,,
test,1.00000,,,
...
```

output:

```
$ sed 's/,,,//' TJ\ -\ 2014-01-03.csv
name,number
test,1.00000
test,2.00000
test,3.00000
...
```

Comment: the rows starting from row 2 and below will be dynamic.. is there a way to do this without knowing what data is in row 2 and below?